# Page load/redirect depending of User session/ login status

Tags: php, redirect

I have a page which includes a members section which is only accessible via login. When logged in a user gets forwarded to the members section, if trying to access the members section without being logged in the user gets redirected to the index page.

What I want is enabling users remaining logged in throughout all pages, and displaying their username and the logout option on top.
However the session file below would by default always redirect back to index:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'user.php';
$session = new USER();

if(!$session->is_loggedin());
{
    // session no set redirects to login page
    $session->redirect('index.php');
}

    ?>
```

The above is fine for all pages that require a login to be accessed but index.php should be accessible with or without being logged in.
The code on top of page:

```
<?php

require_once("session.php");

require_once("user.php");
$auth_user = new USER();


$userid = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid=:userid");
$stmt->execute(array(":userid"=>$userid));

$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    ?>
```

This leads to an endless loop making the `index.php` page inaccessible when not logged in, which kinda makes sense to me. I suppose that I would need either a simple condition to load the page regardless if logged in or not, or an exception within the session file to not redirect on specific pages (the external ones that are accessible with or without login).
I have not included the `user.php` file, as for this the only 2 functions in question are:

```
    public function is_loggedin()
   {
      if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
      {
         return true;
      }
   }

   public function redirect($url)
   {
       header("Location: $url");
   }
```

Comment: You could introduce a check: if the current URL is already `index.php`, just skip the redirect. And, after all: have a look at current ways of structuring your code. Having such code copied to all PHP files means that you have to edit tons of files if you change something in this common logic

Comment: I do not see where you set $_SESSION['user_session'] variable

Comment: This is set within the user class on doLogin:
if(password_verify($password, $userRow['password']))
             {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['userid'];
                return true;
             }
             else
             {
                return false;
             }
          }
       }

Comment: I suggest you to work with a Framework, that provides you most common requirements for web applications like this. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a username or userid session only if logged in
2. If not set redirect to login or wherever you want to redirect
3. Check if the `$_SESSION["username"]` is set or not in every pages just by

   If(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
       {
            redirect
       }

No need to redirect for both cases Or you can create a guest access if want or if you want redirection for both cases

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I came around a solution similar to the above just by moving the session start to index.php and create the condition there which appears to work for me.

```
session_start();
require_once("user.php");
$pageload = new USER();

if($pageload->is_loggedin()!="")

{   
$userid = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$stmt = $load->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid=:userid");
$stmt->execute(array(":userid"=>$userid));

$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```